# Discord JDA: Why is the Reader throwing "Unknown Interaction"

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

i have a button which sends a message into a specific textchannel to ping authorised staff, but everytime its throwing UNKNOWN INTERACTION and is not sending the message. Ive tried many things and i dont know whats wrong and how to fix it, because other buttons work. ereignis is the "event" in german

```
public void onButtonInteraction(ButtonInteractionEvent ereignis) {
if (ereignis.getButton().getId().equals("ssuuii")) {

            if (ereignis.getGuild().getId().equals("GUILD_ID")) {
                ereignis.deferReply().queue();
                ereignis.getGuild().getTextChannelById("TEXTCHANNEL_ID").sendMessage(ereignis.getGuild().getRoleById("ROLE_ID")
                        .getAsMention() + ", " + ereignis.getMember().getAsMention() + " möchte Support haben").queue();
            } else if (ereignis.getGuild().getId().equals("GUILD_ID_A")) {
                ereignis.deferReply().queue();
                ereignis.getGuild().getTextChannelById("TEXTCHANNEL_ID_A").sendMessage("exampleman, " +
                        ereignis.getMember().getAsMention() + " wants Support").queue();
            }

        }
    }
```

and the Button:

```
e.getChannel().sendMessageEmbeds(s.build()).setActionRow(Button.success("ssuuii", "Call Support"))
.complete().delete().queueAfter(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: are you calling `deferReply` multiple times?

Comment: welp for this visualisation, i confounded deferEdit with deferEdit, but only one of them is called due to the if statement, which asks for the guild the button on the message is sent in.

Comment: by getting rid of the "getButton"-order in the first if statement, the console throws null two times

Comment: You should only call a method like `deferEdit`/`deferReply`/... once (for all listeners).